# Both is_dir and is_file return false

Tags: php

I am trying to issue and open_dir function against a particular directory (in my case /home/gregh/Mail), but it is failing.  When I is a check against the directory using is_dir and is_file, they both return false (see below).  I checked the permissions on the directory and the parent directory and both have 775 privs and the apache user even having group membership to the same groups as the owner of the directory.

```
 print("DEBUG - dir = self::SBD_ROOT_PATH = " . self::SBD_ROOT_PATH . " <P>");
 print("DEBUG -   is_dir(self::SBD_ROOT_PATH) = ");
 var_dump(is_dir(self::SBD_ROOT_PATH));
 print("DEBUG -   is_file(self::SBD_ROOT_PATH) = ");
 var_dump(is_file(self::SBD_ROOT_PATH));
```

This yields the following output:

```
 DEBUG - dir = self::SBD_ROOT_PATH = /home/gregh/Mail
 DEBUG - is_dir(self::SBD_ROOT_PATH) = bool(false)
 DEBUG - is_file(self::SBD_ROOT_PATH) = bool(false)
```

Here is some of the directory setting information:

```
[gregh@proteus ~]$ whoami
gregh
[gregh@proteus ~]$ groups
gregh apache admin
[gregh@proteus ~]$ ls -l /home/gregh

drwxrwxr-x.  6 gregh admin  4096 Mar  1 11:46 Mail
```

Then I sudo'd to the "apache user":

```
-bash-4.1$ whoami
apache
-bash-4.1$ groups
apache admin
-bash-4.1$ ls /home/gregh/Mail
7012  7052  email_backup  Errors  float_data  sbd
```

I also added a check to see what:  is_dir("/home/gregh") returns and  is_dir("/home") returns.  Interestingly, is_dir("/home/gregh") returns FALSE and is_dir("/home") returns TRUE.

Specifically, why is the "is_dir" function returning false?  This seems to point to some sort of privilege problem, but I can't figure out what it is.  Any ideas?

Comment: did you check the permissions for `/home/gregh`? Just because `Mail` is world readable doesn't mean apache can actually GET to it to read it. E.g. it's like putting a "free! take one!" bin inside a bank vault. It's free, but you can't reach it anyways.

Comment: Since you changed the permissions after the function returned FALSEt the first time, you might need to clear the file status cache. ´is_dir´ caches its results. Check this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Comment: called clearstatcache() and the results are the same.   Regarding permissions on /home/gregh...it has the same ownership/privs as /home/gregh/Mail.

Comment: Too late to edit my previous comment - the trailing dot in `ls -l`'s permission string indicates you're running SELinux and that directory has a security context. That's where I'd check now.

Comment: SELinux was it!!!  Bit me again.  I usually turn that off when I build a new system and completely forgot.  Thanks DCoder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked for troubleshooting ideas, so these are the extras I would add:

```
clearstatcache();
echo file_exists(self::SBD_ROOT_PATH);
print_r(fstat(self::SBD_ROOT_PATH));
shell_exec('getfacl '.escapeshellarg(self::SBD_ROOT_PATH));
```

The ACL permissions on some versions of Linux have bit me before, which is what the last line is about.

The other thing to watch out for is that Apache/PHP has to reach your directory; if it does not have at least 'rx' permission to all the directories above, then perhaps it cannot get that far?

Comment: Yeah, the getfacl returns all rwx and rx for group and other.  The weird think is I thought I would try an "is_dir" against "/tmp" and that returned true.  However, if I created a subdirectory in /tmp it reuturns false...even if I give 777 privs on the created subdirectory. Oh, and the fstat doesn't work because it says I don't have privileges to the directory...which I do.

Comment: The `fstat` not working sounds key (`is_dir()`, etc. are just wrappers around stat). I see, from comments, that it was SELinux; but if so, why didn't `getfacl()` show it up?